# Is there a way to include the git hash in a github pages site?

Tags: github-pages

Github pages works by using the Markdown static site generator.

Is there a way to make it include the commit hash of the current gh-pages branch, so it is easy to check that a page has been updated, and that everyone is viewing the same version of the site?

Answer (score 3):

This is not specific to GitHub page, and depends on the website generator you are using.
Github pages works with *any* static website generator you want.

For instance, [Hugo](https://gohugo.io) would propose [Git Info Variables](https://gohugo.io/variables/git/), in order to get the last Git revision information for every content file.
[Example](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/hugo-bare-min-theme/blob/eaf1ffeab9915fa2868fdf50f7873a3738bf5860/layouts/_default/baseof.html#L165):

```
    {{ with .GitInfo }} <!-- To enable this, put "enableGitInfo = true" in your site config.toml -->
        {{ $git := . }}
        {{ with $.Site.Params.source }}
            This page was created/modified in commit <a href="{{ .url }}/commit/{{- $git.Hash -}}">
            {{- $git.AbbreviatedHash -}}</a> "{{ $git.Subject }}" on <b>{{ dateFormat "2006-01-02" $git.AuthorDate }}</b>.
        {{ end }}
    {{ end }}
```

---

Regarding  [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), the engine behind [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/), the [OP Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37176/andrew) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60255670/is-there-a-way-to-include-the-git-hash-in-a-github-pages-site/60256492?noredirect=1#comment106619128_60256492) to [this thread](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/expose-the-git-commit-id-in-website/2163/5).

[Suriyaa Kudo](https://github.com/suriyaakudo) used in [`_layouts/default.html`](https://github.com/suriyaakudo/cdn.suriyaa.tk/blob/a337a3ca2e5f3dfd998b2890992f94828be056ec/_layouts/default.html#L14)

```
<!-- build-commit-id: {{ site.github.build_revision }} -->
```

That, after declaring in [`_config.yml`](https://github.com/suriyaakudo/cdn.suriyaa.tk/blob/a337a3ca2e5f3dfd998b2890992f94828be056ec/c)

```
repository: suriyaakudo/cdn.suriyaa.tk
```

You can see it in [26000+ files on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=%22site.github.build_revision%22&type=Code).

Comment: Github pages uses Jekyll static site generator (unless you use your own static site generator and push built pages), it looks as though there may be hints at 
https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/expose-the-git-commit-id-in-website/2163/5
about how to do it, but I am yet to test.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, GitHub does use Jekyll, but does not prevent you to use indeed any static website generator you want.